# How to clear the search results in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm a Rails noob, and am looking for assistance in clearing the results of a search.

I've built a sample application which lists cafes, and have implemented searching using elasticsearch and searchkick. The search function appends parameters to the URL as in http://localhost:3000/cafes?search=sydney&commit=Search and is working correctly.

Now I'd like to add a button to clear the search results:

[image]

The Clear button's link is to the `cafes_path` (http://localhost:3000/cafes), so it basically reloads the page without the search parameters:

```
= form_tag cafes_path, :method => :get do
      = text_field_tag :search
      = submit_tag value = "Search"
      = link_to cafes_path
```

1. Is that an acceptable way to clear the search?
2. Is it an acceptable Rails approach to use JavaScript logic to enable/disable the Clear button, based on what's in the search box?

Please let me know if you need to see more of the model or controller code to make sense of the question.

Comment: Hi, you've just asked a whole  heap of questions - not all of them really Stack-Overflow suitable - we kinda work best with specific, technical questions that have a "right answer" - opinionated questions such as "is this the best way to do this?" aren't a good fit (in the past, such question shave led to flame wars that have torn apart the community, so we avoid them now).

Comment: Fair enough, I've removed the opinion-based aspects of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This way is pretty standard
2. sure, use javascript - or you can also google for other ways it's been done and see what they did.